# Windows Batch file to replace a single character in Windows filenames

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory which consists of many files as below. But my requirement is to change the .CSV filenames only.

Name of the Dir: c:\files\

```
bac.accdb
KFBAROPN.SAVEFILE.CSV
KFBARTRD.SAVEFILE.CSV
```

I have to remove the "."(dot) and replace with hypen(-) . Can you please provide me with a windows batch script file(eg: abc.bat) and also let me know how to schedule to run this file in windows?

I am very new to windows script and your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does it really need to be batch? PowerShell is really the standard on Windows now, and is the better route for readability, sustainability and its easier to learn.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know anything about Windows shell or Powershell. Can you please also let me know how to execute and schedule the powershell script . Please help me with the script. I will try it. Many Thanks VJ

Comment: @user225817 - Do some research and come back and update your question..

Answer (score 1):

try this (cmd shell):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=." %i in ('dir /a-d/b *.*.csv') do @ren "%~i.%~j" "%~i-%~j"
```

.. and for use in a batch script:

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%i in ('dir /a-d/b *.*.csv') do ren "%%~i.%%~j" "%%~i-%%~j"
```

Comment: Hi I placed 4 files in the directory Test. 1. J.BODPOS.20130516.CSV 2. J.BODTRADES.20130516.CSV 3. KFBAROPN.SAVEFILE.CSV 4. KFBARTRD.SAVEFILE.CSV. Created a batch script filen.bat, with the code inside as for /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%i in ('C:\test/a-d/b *.*.CSV') do ren "%%~i.%%~j" "%%~i-%%~j" and when i run getting error as "C:\test>filen.bat 'filen.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Hi I tried this from the cmd prompt and received error . Can you please help me on this. --- for /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%i in ('C:\Documents and Settings\v\ACCESS RECS\test\ /a-d/b *.*.csv') do @ren "%%~i.%%~j" "%%~i-%%~j"

Comment: Error message is "%%i was unexpected at this time."

Comment: on the cmd prompt the for loop variables get only one `%`, eg.  `%i`  !

Comment: Endoro. What should i put in place of "dir" in the script line you provided ?

Comment: If you need to change file names you must list it before. The appropriate list command is `dir`.  I can't imagine, what you mean.