# Windows script to run as a batch to replace character in list of file names

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I have 4 files as below:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\vm\AC R\test

JE.BOS.20130516.CSV
JE.BES.20130516.CSV
KFROPN.SAVEFILE.CSV
KFBAD.SAVEFILE.CSV
```

I have to replace `"."` in the filename with `"-"`. But the extension `.CSV` should remain same.

**1)  I executed the below command and i got the error as below:**

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%i in ('dir /a-d/b *.*.CSV') do ren "%%~i.%%~j" "%%~i-%%~j"
```

Error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\vm\AC R\test>for /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%
i in ('dir /a-d/b *.*.CSV') do ren "%%~i.%%~j" "%%~i-%%~j"
%%i was unexpected at this time.
```

**2) I removed one % before i and executed as below:**

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=." %i in ('dir /a-d/b *.*.CSV') do ren "%%~i.%%~j" "%%~i-%%~j"
```

and got the error as below:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\vmeruga\ACCESS RECS\test>for /f "tokens=1*delims=." %i
 in ('dir /a-d/b *.*.CSV') do ren "%%~i.%%~j" "%%~i-%%~j"

C:\Documents and Settings\vmeruga\ACCESS RECS\test>ren "%JEFFERIES.%BODPOS.20130
516.CSV" "%JE-%BODPOS.20130516.CSV"
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Documents and Settings\vmeruga\ACCESS RECS\test>ren "%JEFFERIES.%BODTRADES.20
130516.CSV" "%JE-%BODTRADES.20130516.CSV"
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Documents and Settings\vmeruga\ACCESS RECS\test>ren "%KFBAROPN.%SAVEFILE.CSV"
 "%KFOPN-%SAVEFILE.CSV"
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Documents and Settings\vmeruga\ACCESS RECS\test>ren "%KFBARTRD.%SAVEFILE.CSV"
 "%KFBARTRD-%SAVEFILE.CSV"
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: I believe that your first try should work if you put it into a batch file.  To run it interactively, change _all_ occurrences of `%%` to `%`.

Comment: @Scott: He got the first command [from an answer to his previous question](http://superuser.com/a/598333/138343). It's clearly incorrect for the filenames provided here and will only replace the *first* period, try it and see.

Comment: @Karan: «I have to replace `"."` in the filename with `"-"`.»  OK, I suppose that could mean that he wants to replace _all_ periods (before the extension).  But I submit that the question is ambiguous.  I interpreted it to mean that the first period was the only one he wanted to change, and the OP doesn’t say anything to clarify that.

Comment: @Scott: Well, I'm assuming he posted this since the solution that does replace the first period did not do what he wanted. Still, you're right, a bit of clarification wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I believe “the solution that does replace the first period did not do what he wanted” because he typed it interactively with `%%i` instead of `%i`, etc… –– see the error message he reported.

Comment: @Scott: Ok, I see no point us debating this ad infinitum without the OP chiming in with what *he* wants, so let's wait for him to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, save the following as a .BAT file and execute:

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion&&for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.csv') do @set fn=%%~na&&set fn=!fn:.=-!&&ren "%%a" "!fn!%%~xa"
```

Comment: Karan. When i run this script from test directory it works. What if would like to run it from any directory/path. I need to mention the path name in the script right!. Can you please tell me where do i modify the script to specify the path as "c:\test\"

Comment: @user225817: A simple `cd /d "drive:\path\to\dir"` as the first line will take you to the dir you want to run the rest of the batch in, but I guess you already figured that out. You can [accept the answer by clicking the empty green check mark](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask) to the left. It will become filled on clicking.

Answer (score 0):

try this, look at the output and remove the word `echo`, if it is OK:

```
@echo off&setlocal
cd /d "C:\Documents and Settings\vm\AC R\test"
for %%i in (*.*.csv) do (
    set "fname=%%~ni"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "nname=!fname:.=-!"
    echo rename "!fname!.CSV" "!nname!.CSV"
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Endoro. I tried the above script putting in a batch file, I am not sure whether i should put in a batch file or run in a coomad line. As a batch file, I couldn't see the results. Thanks for your time on this issue.